# When I attempt to create a JSON Object in Python, It errors, despite having validated the JSON Online

Tags: python, json

I believe that the issue is due to python formatting all ' to ", which would result in the error message which I recieved upon running the program.
My Code is as follows:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
username = input('enter username here: ')
print('')
passw = input('enter password here: ')
mcpayload = {"agent": {"name": "Minecraft", "version": 1}, "username": "{}".format(username), "password": "{}".format(passw), "requestUser": "true"}
header = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
logintoken = requests.post('https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate', data = mcpayload, headers = header)
print(logintoken.text)
print('')
print(logintoken.json)
print('')
print(logintoken.content)
```

It returns this err message on run:

```
{"error":"JsonParseException","errorMessage":"Unrecognized token 'agent': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')\n at [Source: (org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInputOverHTTP); line: 1, column: 7]"}

<bound method Response.json of <Response [400]>>

b'{"error":"JsonParseException","errorMessage":"Unrecognized token \'agent\': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token \'null\', \'true\' or \'false\')\\n at [Source: (org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInputOverHTTP); line: 1, column: 7]"}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not sending json string but you are sending a python dictionary. you would need to convert it to json first then send it.

You will need to use json.dumps to convert dictionary object to json string.

```
header=json.dumps(header) #converting dict to json
mcpayload=json.dumps(mcpayload) #converting dict to json
```

The code should look like this:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
username = input('enter username here: ')
print('')
passw = input('enter password here: ')
mcpayload = {"agent": {"name": "Minecraft", "version": 1}, "username": "{}".format(username), "password": "{}".format(passw), "requestUser": "true"}
header = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

header=json.dumps(header) #converting dict to json
mcpayload=json.dumps(mcpayload) #converting dict to json

logintoken = requests.post('https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate', data = mcpayload, headers = header)
print(logintoken.text)
print('')
print(logintoken.json)
print('')
print(logintoken.content)
```

Comment: Thank you! I managed to fix the error message by changing "data = mcpayload" to "data = json.dumps(mcpayload)". I understand my mistake in which datatype I was using now. The API I am sending a POST request to expects json formatted as a string. I am rather new to JSON formatting and API requests so this is useful knowledge for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send JSON, pass the JSON object via the kwarg `json`, not `data`:

```py
logintoken = requests.post(
    'https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate',
    json=mcpayload
)
```

Also, you can omit sending the custom header then, since `requests.post()` will automagically serialize the object for you and set appropriate headers.